# Desfoque em uma área específica com OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

Estou tentando desfocar um rosto encontrado em um vídeo utilizando OpenCV mas estou tendo o seguinte erro:

> cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.0) /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/filter.simd.hpp:220: error: (-215:Assertion failed) src && dst && count > 0 in function 'FilterEngine__proceed

Executei um outro código com a mesma lógica mudando a entrada para uma imagem estática e funciona perfeitamente.

Linha em que ocorre o erro:

> frame[x:x+w, y:y+h] = cv2.blur(frame[x:x+w, y:y+h], (23, 23))

Código completo:

```
import cv2
import sys
import numpy

#argumento para entrada de arquivos de video
video = sys.argv[1]
#argumento para entrada de classificadores
cascPath = sys.argv[2]

#carrega o arquivo de classificacao treinado
faceCascades = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascPath)

#capturando o video
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video)

while(1):
    #lendo a imagem
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    #passando a imagem para cinza
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    #localizando faces
    faces = faceCascades.detectMultiScale(
        gray,
        scaleFactor=1.1,
        minNeighbors=5,
        minSize=(30,30),
        flags=cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE
    )

    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        frame[x:x+w, y:y+h] = cv2.blur(frame[x:x+w, y:y+h], (23, 23))

        #exibindo o frame processado
        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)


    #aguardando tecla para finalizar o programa
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break

#destroi todas janelas abertas 
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Não consegui encontrar nenhum conteúdo mais detalhado sobre OpenCV além da documentação, portanto, caso alguém tenha uma boa referência de estudos sobre o tema, será muito bem-vinda.

Comment: Mudei a linha indicada mas o erro persiste.

Comment: Fiz o teste com o classificador `/data/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml` e com a webcam `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)`. O código rodou sem erros, somente não está funcionando corretamente. O problema pode estar na forma em que seu vídeo é capturado pelo OpenCV.

Comment: Estou utilizando um vídeo .mp4 bem curto, tentei mudar o vídeo e o erro continua, porém agora ele chega a inicializar (coisa que não acontecia antes). Reparei que o erro ocorre justamente quando aparece alguma face no vídeo. O problema começou a acontecer quando eu adicionei a parte do blur. Localizar faces e desenhar alguma forma geométrica sobre ela funciona normalmente.